# Display array element from JSON data

Tags: jquery, json

I've got some buttons on a page- say 'BTN A, 'BTN B', 'BTN C'.

If someone clicks on BTN A, a loop should run on JSON DATA and search for TITLE's on jobcategory JSON object and if it is equal to the TITLE, we need to alert its TITLE and its ID.

ANy suggestions please?

JSON DATA

```
"jobcategory": [
{"TITLE":"A","ID":"27"},
{"TITLE":"B","ID":"15"},
{"TITLE":"C ","ID":"28"}
]
```

So far I've coded as below- but its alerting all TITLE instead of alerting just one

```
$("button").click( function() {
$.each(data.jobcategory, function(k, v) {
alert(data.jobcategory[k]);
});
```

Thanks in Advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have `btn A` like this:

`<button data-title="A">Click Me</button>`

Then:

```
$( "button" ).click( function() {
    var btnTitle = $( this ).data( "title" );
    $.each( data.jobcategory, function( k, v ) {
        if ( v.TITLE === btnTitle )
            alert( v );
} );
```

Comment: Updated answer. Using `v` instead of `data.jobcategory`.